# How to apply security group rules in different regions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I need help in writing a terraform script fro AWS as follows:

I have a list of security groups in multiple regions, for example, 
 - us-east-2
 - us-west-1
 - etc.

Now when I add a new instance in any of the region, I am applying an EIP. 
I need to add that EIP all traffic in every region's security group.

So far what I tried:

- Saving the EIP in a file called node_ips.txt
- Read that file
- Apply it to security group

Here is the script sample:

```
variable "list_eips" { type=list" }    
resource "aws_eip_association" "eip_assoc" {
      count = "${local.number_of_instances}"
      instance_id   = "${element(aws_instance.ec2_instance.*.id, count.index)}"
      allocation_id = "${element(data.aws_eip.db_ip.*.id, count.index)}"   
      provisioner "local-exec" {
         command = "echo ${self.public_ip} >> node_ips.txt"
      }
    }

    data "template_file" "read_node_ips" {
      template = "${file("${path.cwd}/node_ips.txt")}"
    }



    resource "aws_security_group_rule" "allow_db_communication" {
      type            = "ingress"
      from_port       = 0
      to_port         = 65535
      protocol        = "tcp"
      cidr_blocks     = ["${split(",", "${join("/32,",  concat(compact(split("\n",data.template_file.read_node_ips.rendered)),var.list_eips)  )}/32")}"]
      security_group_id = "${data.aws_security_group.cassandra_sg.id}"
    }
```

This is not working for me. It is adding rules only for list_eips.
Again, when I add a new instance in different region, the secruity group is different. So, I am not able to know what was my security group in previous region.
Please advise any idea.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Terraform has the idea of "Multiple Provider Instances", You can create providers for each region that need to access and manipulate resources.

```
# West coast region
provider "aws" {
  alias  = "west"
  region = "us-west-2"
}

resource "aws_instance" "foo" {
  provider = "aws.west"

  # ...
}
```

https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/providers.html